# Sliding Tabs with RecycleView Fragments and Swipe to Refresh

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

i'm having some issues implementing a Sliding Tabs activity that contains 2 Fragments and a Swipe Down to Refresh layout, namely implementing the Swipe Down to Refresh part (the rest is working just fine).

First here are my XML files.

The Main Activity XML , which contains the ViewPager wrapped in an SwipeRefreshLayout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context="com.example.popal.soul.MovieListActivityTEST">

<com.example.popal.soul.SlidingTabLayout
 android:id="@+id/tabs"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:elevation="2dp"
 android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>


<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And the first tab XML , one of the 2 tabs (both are similar, so i`ll only post one)

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cardList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, my main activity, which handles the ViewPager, Adapter an the SlidingTabsLayout.

```
public class MovieListActivityTEST extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
CharSequence Titles[]={"Home","Events"};
int Numboftabs =2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_list_activity_test);

    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); 

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
}
```

And finally, my fragment for the first Tab

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {


public MovieListAdapter movieListAdaptor;
public RecyclerView recycleList;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;

private List<MovieListAdapter.MovieDetails> movieList = new ArrayList<MovieListAdapter.MovieDetails>();

private ProgressBar progressBar;
private final static String MOVIES_POST_REQUEST ="//Long String, Edited out since it`s not relevant"


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);

    recycleList = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardList);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recycleList.setLayoutManager(llm);


   swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {


            movieListAdaptor.clear();
            new Send_data_to_server().execute(MOVIES_POST_REQUEST);
            swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }); 
    new Send_data_to_server().execute(MOVIES_POST_REQUEST);
    return v;
}
```

The issue is, i'm getting a NULL Pointer Exception at `swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {...}` method, which i guess is because the Swipe-to-Refresh layout is in the main activity XML, and not the tabs fragment. So what is the proper way to implement this ? I also tried implementing a Swipe to refresh layout in one of the Tabs XML instead of wrapping the ViewPager in it, like above, but it would crash when swiping from tab to another.

Here`s the code from the entire fragment in Tab1, for tobs answer below

```
public class MoviesTabFragment extends Fragment implements Refreshable {


public MovieListAdapter movieListAdaptor;
public RecyclerView recycleList;
//private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;

public List<MovieListAdapter.MovieDetails> movieList = new ArrayList<MovieListAdapter.MovieDetails>();

public ProgressBar progressBar;
public final static String MOVIES_POST_REQUEST ="";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);

    recycleList = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardList);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recycleList.setLayoutManager(llm);

    new Send_data_to_server().execute(MOVIES_POST_REQUEST);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void refresh() {
    new Send_data_to_server().execute(MOVIES_POST_REQUEST);
}


public class Send_data_to_server extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private String data_poster;
    private String data_fanart;

 //   protected void onPreExecute() {
   //     progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 //   }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        String jason_data = params[0];
        HttpClient http_con = new HttpClient();
        String output_from_server = http_con.establish_con(jason_data);
        Log.i("DataFromServer", output_from_server);

        JSONObject json_Obj = null;
        JSONObject child_obj = null; //creating the "result" object in the main JSON Object
        try {
            json_Obj = new JSONObject(output_from_server);
            child_obj = create_subObject("result", json_Obj);
            JSONArray jsonArray = child_obj.optJSONArray("movies");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String title_data = jsonObject.optString("label").toString();
                String plot_data = jsonObject.optString("plot").toString();
                String year_data =  jsonObject.optString("year").toString();
                String movie_id_data = jsonObject.optString("movieid").toString();
                String imdb_score = jsonObject.optString("rating").toString();
                String imdb_score_short = imdb_score.substring(0, 3);

                JSONObject child_obj2 = create_subObject("art", jsonObject);

                data_poster = child_obj2.optString("poster").toString();
                data_fanart = child_obj2.optString("fanart").toString();

                JSONEncodePosterFanart encodePosterFanart = new JSONEncodePosterFanart();

                String jason_dataPoster = encodePosterFanart.GetPosterFanartEncodedURL(data_poster);
                String jason_dataFanart = encodePosterFanart.GetPosterFanartEncodedURL(data_fanart);

                HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
                String output_from_serverPoster = http.establish_con(jason_dataPoster);

                HttpClient http2 = new HttpClient();
                String output_from_serverFanart = http2.establish_con(jason_dataFanart);

                JSONPosterFanart poster_fanart = new JSONPosterFanart();
                String post_dl = poster_fanart.GetPosterFanart(output_from_serverPoster);

                JSONPosterFanart poster_fanart2 = new JSONPosterFanart();
                String fanart_dl = poster_fanart2.GetPosterFanart(output_from_serverFanart);

                if (null == movieList) {
                    movieList = new ArrayList<MovieListAdapter.MovieDetails>();
                }

                MovieListAdapter.MovieDetails item = new MovieListAdapter.MovieDetails(title_data+" ("+year_data+")", post_dl, fanart_dl,plot_data,movie_id_data,imdb_score_short);
                movieList.add(item);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return output_from_server;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String output_from_server) {

        super.onPostExecute(output_from_server);
        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        movieListAdaptor = new MovieListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
        recycleList.setAdapter(movieListAdaptor);
    }

    private  JSONObject create_subObject(String tagName, JSONObject jObj) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject subObj = jObj.getJSONObject(tagName); //getJSONObject returns the value from tagName (in our case jason_Obj that is being passed ar a param)
        return subObj;
    }

}
```

}

And the RecycleView adapter:

```
 public class MovieListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieListAdapter.MovieViewHolder> {

public List<MovieDetails> movieList;
private Context mContext;

public MovieListAdapter(Context mContext, List<MovieDetails> movieList) {

    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.movieList = movieList;
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return movieList.size();
}

public void clear() {
    movieList.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}



@Override
public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(viewGroup.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.card_layout_movies_list, viewGroup, false);
    return new MovieViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MovieViewHolder movieViewHolder, int i) {


    MovieDetails mdet = movieList.get(i);

    String fanart = "http://192.168.1.128/"+mdet.getImageViewFanart();
    String poster = "http://192.168.1.128/"+mdet.getImageViewPoster();

    Log.i("fanart", fanart);
    Log.i("poster", poster);

    movieViewHolder.vTitle.setText(mdet.Title);

    Picasso.with(mContext).load(poster)
            .resize(500, 746)
            .error(R.drawable.poster_placeholder)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.poster_placeholder)
            .into(movieViewHolder.vPoster);
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(fanart)
            .resize(960, 540)
            .error(R.drawable.fanart_placeholder)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.fanart_placeholder)
            .into(movieViewHolder.vFanart);

    movieViewHolder.vplot = mdet.getPlot();
    movieViewHolder.vmovie_id = mdet.getMovie_id();


}

public  class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    protected TextView vTitle;
    protected ImageView vPoster;
    protected ImageView vFanart;
    protected String vplot;
    protected String vmovie_id;
    protected String vimdb_score;

    public MovieViewHolder(View v)
    {
        super(v);
        vplot = new String();
        vmovie_id = new String();
        vimdb_score = new String();
        vTitle  = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        vPoster = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPoster);
        vFanart = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewFanart);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getLayoutPosition();
        MovieDetails mov = movieList.get(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MovieDetailsPageActivity.class);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("movieid", mov.getMovie_id());
        bundle.putString("plot", vplot);
        bundle.putString("fanart_path", mov.getImageViewFanart());
        bundle.putString("imdb_score", mov.getImdb_score());
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);

    }
}


public static class MovieDetails {

    protected String Title;
    protected String imageViewPoster;
    protected String imageViewFanart;
    protected String plot;
    protected String movie_id;
    protected String imdb_score;

    public MovieDetails(String Title, String imageViewPoster,String imageViewFanart, String plot, String movie_id ,String imdb_score)
    {
        this.Title = Title;
        this.imageViewPoster = imageViewPoster;
        this.imageViewFanart = imageViewFanart;
        this.plot = plot;
        this.movie_id = movie_id;
        this.imdb_score = imdb_score;
    }

    public String getTitle() {return Title;}

    public String getImageViewPoster() {
        return imageViewPoster;
    }

    public String getImageViewFanart() {
        return imageViewFanart;
    }

    public String getPlot() {return plot;}

    public String getMovie_id() {return movie_id;}

    public String getImdb_score() {return imdb_score;}

}
```

}

```
 public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

CharSequence Titles[]; 
int NumbOfTabs; 


public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
    super(fm);

    this.Titles = mTitles;
    this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    if(position == 0) 
    {
        MoviesTabFragment moviesTabFragment = new MoviesTabFragment();
        return moviesTabFragment;
    }
    else             
    {
        TVShowsTabFragment TVShowsTabFragment = new TVShowsTabFragment();
        return TVShowsTabFragment;
    }

}


@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return Titles[position];
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NumbOfTabs;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the `NullPointerException` because you inflate your fragment layout from `R.layout.tab_1` which does not contain a `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

If you want the layout to be the parent of your `ViewPager`, I would recommend you to move your code which manages the RefreshLayout to the MainActivity:

```
public class MovieListActivityTEST extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
CharSequence Titles[]={"Home","Events"};
int Numboftabs =2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_list_activity_test);

    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); 

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);

    // Assign your refresh layout
    refreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

    refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            Refreshable r = (Refreshable) adapter.getItemAt(pager.getCurrentItem());
            r.refresh();
        }
    }); 
}
```

where each of your tab fragments implements a `Refreshable` interface:

```
public interface Refreshable {
    void refresh();
}
```

and your adapter keeps track on all fragments:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    // list that keeps references to all attached Fragments
    private SparseArray<Fragment> pages = new SparseArray<>();
    ...

    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment f;
        if(position == 0) {
            ...
        } else { ... }

        // add fragment to the list
        pages.put(position, f);
    }

     public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // remove fragment from list if it existed
        if(pages.indexOfKey(position) >= 0) {
            pages.remove(position);
        }

        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    // return the attached Fragment that is associated with the given position
    public Fragment getItemAt(int position) {
        return pages.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , tried you're idea, created a Refreshable interface and implemented the refresh method() from the interface it in the first tab for testing. But i'm getting a NULL Pointer exception when it executes the `Send_data_to_server().execute(MOVIES_POST_REQUEST)` enclosed class, which is an AsyncTask that talks to my server, retrieves  JSON data from it, and sets the Adaptor of the RecycleView with CardList . The error is exactly at the part where i set the RecycleView adapter. I've added the entire code of tab fragment in an answer below (since you can't format code properly in comments

Comment: The creation of the adapter for the RecicleView is in the 'OnPostExecute' method, at the end of the class, by the way. Maybe it has something to do with getActivity() used when creating the adapter, since from my limited knowlege, that can return NULL in certain situations in case of Fragments.

Comment: Yup, just added `if(getActivity()==null){Log.i("Activity Status","It`s NULL");}` to the refresh method, and according to the log, it is NULL. Also added the entire code to the first question and deleted the answer added by me

Comment: I tried adding the Context by using the onAttach method, `public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
      
        super.onAttach(activity);
        context=activity;
    }` and using getContext() in the adapter creation method, but still the same issue.

Comment: Done, added the RecycleView adapter code at the end of my question. As a side note, the code works fine when i use an activity instead of a fragment (before i had sliding tabs implemented, so no fragments) both he initialization and the refresh, the issue only comes up when using the `public void refresh` method in the fragment (when `Send_data_to_server().execute(MOVIES_POST_REQUEST)` is called from the onCreateView it also works fine).

Comment: Sorry I was a bit unclear :). I meant your viewpager adapter

Comment: Done, just added it at the end of the question. MoviesTabFragment in the adapter is actually Tab1 Fragment class (i renamend it a couple of minutes ago) , and TvShowsFragment is the Tab2 Fragment class.

Comment: Ok, sorry, It was my fault. You're calling `adapter.getItem()` in the refresh listener, but if you look at the implementation, it simply returns a new instance of the fragment which is not attached to the view pager and therefore has no parent activity. I will edit my answer shortly.

Comment: Yup, you`re right and it makes sense, works like a charm now. Thanks a lot for the assistance, i also marked your answer as solved.